# Change Input borders after filling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to change bottom line color of input after input filled some info. One important condition - if input after filling still empty( for example user tapped at input, then decided not to fill it and tap out of input) color has not to be changed.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("fname");
input.onchange = function(e) {
if(input.value != '') {
  e.target.style.borderBottom = "1px solid #ccffcc";
}
};
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="fname" id="name">NAME</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="">
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

Comment: you can use of keyup method for change the color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`:valid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:valid) CSS pseudo-class

```css
.custom-border {
  outline: none;
}

.custom-border:valid {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccffcc;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="fname" id="name">NAME</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="" class="custom-border" required>
  <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks. I did it before ask a question, but it didn't work. Maybe because i used few pseudoclasess in one declaration.

Comment: @User863 I have multiple inputs, how to make each of them change border color when the cursor places in them?